# Generic#to, but with Field Names?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Using `Generic#to`, I can get the `HList` representation of a `case class`:

```
import shapeless._
case class F(x: Int, y: String)

scala> Generic[F].to( F(1, "foo") )
res1: shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]] = 
    1 :: foo :: HNil
```

However, I'd like to get the following representation:

`("x", 1) :: ("y", "foo") :: HNil`

In other words, instead of just the `F` instance's fields' values, I'd like to get the field names, i.e. `x` and `y`, as well.

How can I get this representation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`LabelledGeneric`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/labelledgeneric.scala).

In order to print the fields, you can then use the `Fields` type class (from the `ops.record` package), which can be invoked with `.fields` if you import also the `record` package.

Here's a full example

```
import shapeless._, record._, ops.record._
case class F(x: Int, y: String)    

scala> LabelledGeneric[F].to(F(1, "foo")).fields
res1: shapeless.::[(Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("x")], Int),shapeless.::[(Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("y")], String),shapeless.HNil]] = ('x,1) :: ('y,foo) :: HNil
```

If you also want to convert the keys to `String`:

```
object keysToString extends Poly1 {
  implicit def keyToName[A, B] = at[(Symbol with A, B)] { case (k, v) => (k.name, v) }
}

scala> LabelledGeneric[F].to(F(1, "foo")).fields.map(keysToString)
res2: shapeless.::[(String, Int),shapeless.::[(String, String),shapeless.HNil]] = (x,1) :: (y,foo) :: HNil
```